# My selection automatically inverts in Photoshop. How do I correct it?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, selections

Whenever I make a selection it automatically inverts the selection. How do I correct it?

Comment: well, thats wague can you actually explain how you figures this out what you do etc.

Comment: @joojaa let's say you have a ball on a white background. You want to Cut the ball out and delete it. You trace out the ball with the pentool, then Ctrl+Entre to make selection and click delete. Only this time, it is the white background that deletes instead of the ball. It's like an automatic Ctrl+Shift+I, when I press Ctrl+E. Do you get me? 

Comment: Ok thats clear but the thing is you failed to mention the tool you were using theres lots of ways of making selection is PS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you choose the pen tool, go up to your tool menu bar and look for the overlapping squares:

[image]

Click on the overlapping squares and you'll get a dialog box - check to make sure that "Subtract Front Shape" isn't checked. Should be the bottom selection, "Exclude Overlapping Shapes"

[image]